# ADOQuery,SQL Statements and Reordering of rows within a database

Tags: sql, database, delphi, ado

I have a database Table Named P_Columns. This Table Contains the columns

```
ID
Column_Name
Column_Type
Column_Visible
Column_Order
```

This Data table gets populated and updated by an Application which displays a dbgrid.
This application has a button.  that when clicked it takes the selected row. and moves it up one row (This is where I need help).

Now my initial SQL Statement (SELECT * FROM P_Columns Order by Column_Order asc) sets the correct order. initially.

I need to find out if there is an update Sql statement that will allow me to swap the Column_Order of the selected record. with that of the record just before it.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Which dbms is this connecting to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Delphi code that does what you want using TADOCommand calling an update statement twice. This is tested against MS SQL Server. If you do not use TADO* components you should be able to convert to whatever database components you use. ADODataSet1 is the data that is presented in the grid.

```
var
    CurrentID: Integer;
    CurrentOrder: Integer;
    PrevID: Integer;
    PrevOrder: Integer;
begin
    if ADODataSet1.RecNo > 1 then // Do not move the first row
    begin
        CurrentID := ADODataSet1['ID'];
        CurrentOrder := ADODataSet1['Column_Order'];

        ADODataSet1.Prior;
        PrevID := ADODataSet1['ID'];
        PrevOrder := ADODataSet1['Column_Order'];

        ADOCommand1.CommandText := 'update P_Columns set Column_Order = :Column_Order where ID = :ID';

        ADOCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('Column_Order').Value := PrevOrder;
        ADOCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := CurrentID;
        ADOCommand1.Execute;

        ADOCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('Column_Order').Value := CurrentOrder;
        ADOCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := PrevID;
        ADOCommand1.Execute;

        ADODataSet1.Requery([]);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked out the best. 
I appreciate everyone posts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it for you...

```
update P_Columns 
set Column_Order = ((select count(*) from P_Columns) + 1) - Column_Order
```

Comment: What I'm doing here is taking the count of the records, incrementing it by 1 and then subtracting the current Column_Order...so the Column_Order column starts with 1,2,3...5 and goes to 5,4,3...1.

Answer (score 0):

Swap just two positions. The last `AND :order > 1` is used so that position 1 cannot be swapped with position 0 (non-existent)

```
update datatable
set column_order = case 
                      when column_order = :order then column_order-1 
                      else column_order+1 
                   end
where column_order in (:order, :order-1)
  and :order > 1
```

The `CASE` statement should exist in most major DBMS.

Note: there is a bug in (stock) TADOQuery that will not set the parameter all 4 `:order` parameters in one go.  4 parameters will be required all carrying the same value, unless the DBMS is known to optimize the query for a specific DBMS.

Comment: You are assuming that `column_order` a) is numeric, and b) has no gaps in its sequence. Are these assumptions due? You could fix your code by using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_order)` or equivalent then apply your logic to the resulting column.

Comment: @one - there is a comment about DBMS pending. The question suggests that there are no gaps, but OP can clarify if that is untrue.

Comment: "The question suggests that there are no gaps" -- where does it say that? Ditto the data type being integer (or numeric).

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems like in this case you don't have to have one statement only solution. Neither do I see it implied, as you were only talking about *an UPDATE* statement, which doesn't mean you cannot have any other statements preparing your update, does it? But if you did have that in mind, forgive me, please, yet I am going to move on. :)

First, I would like to know if your `Column_Order` has indeed no gaps. Because if there's no gaps *and* the values start from 1, then you can get away with cyberkiwi's solution with only this modification (yet all credit should go to that person):

```
declare @order int;
set @order = :order;

update P_Columns
set Column_Order =
  case 
    when Column_Order = @order then Column_Order - 1 
    else Column_Order + 1 
  end
where Column_Order in (@order, @order - 1) and @order > 1
```

That is, you need to declare a @var so you only use `:order` once per script. (You may probably have known that already.) And there you are.

However, if that solution cannot be applied as is, then basically, I think, you just need to add more statements to calculate beforehand the other order value due to be swapped, then update.

Here's what it can be like:

```
declare @order int, @prev_order int;
set @order = :order;

/* here goes looking up for the other Column_Order */
select @prev_order = max(Column_Order)
from P_Columns
where Column_Order < @order;

/* and now update, which is basically the same,
   only adapted for use with @prevorder,
   and also we check if @prevorder has a value */
if @prevorder is not null
  update P_Columns
  set Column_Order =
    case Column_Order
      when @order then @prevorder
      else @order
    end
  where Column_Order in (@order, @prevorder)
```

If you have any questions, they are welcome.